# React doesn't show errors in terminal and browser

Tags: compiler-errors, create-react-app

I've created a new app with react-create-app.
Here's my code:

```
function App() {
  let m;
  console.log(m); // undefined
  console.log(m.prop); // should throw an error
  return (
    <div className="App">
        App
    </div>
  );
}
```

My app compiles successfully and I can see this error only in the chrome devtools console, but not in the IDE terminal or in the browser's page. Browser shows me an empty page, how can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can use - try catch -, and if something happen you could render the text of the error in the browser.

Example:

```
function App() {
  let m;
  console.log(m); // undefined
  try {
    console.log(m.prop); // should throw an error
  } catch (e) {
    return (<h1>{e.toString()}</h1>);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
        App
    </div>
  );
}
```

or

```
function App() {
  const [error, setError] = React.useState();
  let m;
  console.log(m); // undefined
  try {
    console.log(m.prop); // should throw an error
  } catch (e) {
    setError(e.toString());
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
        App
        { error && <h1>{error}</h1> }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this is not what I'am looking for. I just want to configure the default create-react-app error messages.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible but if you put a try and catch in top level component like in the example i think is the same. Any throw of error of any component is going to be catch and behaved like you programed, for example showing the message of error with some styles in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Your `package.json` should be configured to include these packages in the "key dependencies" section:

```
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
"@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
"web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
```

You also have to add the following in same level as "dependencies" of `package.json` object:

```
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
},
```

Then `npm install` and `npm start`.

```
{
  "name": "reactapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```